# WPAPI: Parent Page not shown in WP UI for API created pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wp-api

I am using the WP-API to create Wordpress pages via API. As I have a nested structure I want to create pages which have parent pages. This seems to work fine. However, when I view these pages inside the WP UI page detail view the parent pages are not shown in the Parent Attributes box. The parent is also not visible in the dropdown list.
Instead, in the pages overview list, the title is shown with wired dashes ('---'). I had a look into the DB and it shows the parents correctly. Does anyone know why it is so weirdly shown in the UI? Am I doing something wrong?

I am using node-wpapi, a JavaScript Client for the Wordpress REST API.
http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/using-the-client/

This is how I am creating the page:

```
function createPage(title, content, parent) {
    console.log(parent);
    var wp = new WPAPI({
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json',
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'pass'
    });
    return wp.pages().create({
        title: title,
        content: content,
        parent: parent,
        status: 'publish'
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error: ' + error.message);
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        return response.id;
    })
}
```

[image: child with wired dashes]
[image: no parent is shown]

Comment: What UI do you expect to see? Are you speaking of the list in the Admin pages area?

Comment: yes the wp-admin dashboard/pages

Comment: The dashes are are correct. They show the child status of a page.

Comment: but why isn't the parent shown under 'parent pages' when I click on one of these pages?

Comment: If you open the detail view of a page that is displayed with those dashes, the parent page of this child page should be displayed in one of the boxes there. I don't understand the behavior that you expect. The box is titled 'Parent Attributes' and shows a dropdown. This should contain the name of the parent page.

Comment: Screenshots would really help...

Comment: @jasie i added two pictures. in the first you can see that the element is a child element. In the second in the lower right corner it says "no parent". Do you understand what i mean now?

Comment: Are your pages public?

Comment: yes all of them are public

Comment: Is the parent page that you assigned visible in the dropdown list (in the Page Attributes box) and simply not selected?

Comment: no actually it is not. That's also very strange

Comment: This is usually the case, if the parent page is not public.. Are there any pages in the dropdown list?

Comment: as I create all of them via the API they have all the same attributes: public / published etc. No, there are no pages in the dropdown list

Comment: How do your page IDs look like?

Comment: It's a number. I checked with the DB and it is always the right parent ID always. It's always the ID of the parent's post. (e.g. parent post id=15, then the child has as poast_parent: 15)

Comment: Last idea: what happens, if you manually create a page via UI - does it show up in the dropdown list? Can you assign it as parent?

Comment: yes, that works. The manually created pages are shown in the dropdown lists.

Comment: Also: did you activate Error Logging: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG
If yes, what's in it? If not, do it.

Comment: Okay, then I suggest you do this: compare the "invisible" pages with the visible page in the database, all columns. Can you find a difference?

Comment: the only thing that's kind of different is the GUID. The API created one looks like this: 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/1-2/authorizepayment/authorizepaymentrequest/'
The manual created one: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/?page_id=279.
Does that matter?

Comment: Yes it does. Please post a screenshot of the database entries of API-created pages and a manually created page.

Comment: Here someone says, it is not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726709/wp-insert-post-and-guid-issue-wordpress I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should create a new issue in the node-wpapi Github here:
https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi/issues

Comment: thank you for all your time & help, i did add an issue :)

Comment: You're welcome, I enjoyed the debugging and your cooperation. Good luck with the issue.